# while loop check for two values seperated by comma

Tags: c, while-loop

I have come across some code where it looks like this.

```
while(1, N)
```

where `N` can an integer ranging from 0 - 100.

Can somebody tell how can we use while loop like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(1, N)
```

is equivalent to

```
while(N)
```

as the comma operator yields the value of the right operand. So using the first form is useless.

If you want to write a loop that is run from `1` to `N` (including), you can use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about "comment", that contradicts the fact that the result of the comma expression is the right-hand side. `while(0, N)` behaves just like `while(1, N)`.

Comment: @unwind I'm saying non-sense, removing this part.

Comment: while(1, 0, 0, 1, 1) yields true, where as while(1, 1, 0, 0, 0) yields false. I am wondering what sort of calculation is done

Comment: @vijaykumar `a, b, c` is equivalent to `(a, b), c`, so the result value is the value of right most operand (1 in your first example and 0 in your second example).

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I agree that Ouah. Below is the scenario I have encountered the code.  If it is a blank line, it would not enter inside the loop                                                                                                                             while (sscanf(gets(line), "%d", &N), N)

Answer (score 3):

As per the `C11` standard document, chapter 6.5.17, comma operator,

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

So, essentially,

```
while(1, N)
```

is same as

```
 while(N)
```